# not able to get knockout template working in an existing page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have a simple knockout template but because it's within an existing page that uses knockout I'm failing to get my template working.  I'm not seeing Hello on the page.  Any advice appriecated! Thanks,

**code snippet**

```
<script type="text/html" id="childtag-template">
    <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'tag-template'}"></ul>
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'keyword-template'}"></div>  <!-- new bit -->
</script>
```

**template**

```
<script type="text/html" id="keyword-template">
  hello
</script>
```

In the document ready event for the page the following is present

**page on load**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        window.helper.Start(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)););
    });
```

Contents of Start is below

**start method**

```
window.Helper= {
    Start: function (x) {
        var viewModel = Helper.XViewModel(x);
        window.Helper.ViewModel = viewModel;
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        ...
```

When I can successfully load a template I just need a simple form taken straight from knockout examples that allows a list to be added to and deleted from.  I have this working in isolation but when putting the markup and js into the existing file I get js errors.

**UPDATE**

I've added the following change (see the viewModel.Keywords).  Firefox reports no errors but I don't see my hello on the page.

```
window.Helper = {
    Start: function (x) {
        var viewModel = Helper.XViewModel(x);
        window.ArticleManagerHelper.ViewModel = viewModel;
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

        viewModel.Keywords = ko.observable();  // new line of code
```

I've added the following into the template

```
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Keywords"/>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what JS errors you're getting?

Comment: im not getting any errors now although I'm still not able to see my message

Comment: window.helper.Start should be window.Helper.Start in your *case*...ha ha...I kill me.

Comment: Can you post what the view model is when it is serialised pls? So I can create a fiddle.

Comment: where can I post a long string temporarily?

Comment: Just in the answer as an update, as an example like this: var data = ; window.helper.Start({"Users":[{"Id":1,"Name":"bob"}]});

Comment: go here http://jamesradford.net/temp.txt  Notice the last property is something I've added to the c# model to try and get this working thanks

Comment: Nice one, thanks. Will give it a go, I have to go out in 5 mins. Someone will probably figure it out before me but i'll try. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is what I did to get it working.

Please note I used a simplified version of the json so I could create a working jsFiddle but the concepts are still the same.

```
<!--html -->
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'keyword-template', data: Article }"></div>

<!-- template -->
<script type="text/html" id="keyword-template">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Keywords"/>
</script>
```

1. You had both parts defined in templates, you needed the binding part in html sitting outside of a template. Unless I have got it wrong and it is some kind of nested template and the outer html is missing, sorry if this is the case.
2. I needed to specify the data for it to bind to i.e. `data: Article`

Here is the link to the jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Yfu2Y/1/

Comment: thanks, I've made that change but I get the same response as before?? (i.e 'hello' doesn't appear on the page)

Comment: window.helper.Start should be window.Helper.Start in your 'case'...ha ha...I kill me...twice!

Comment: Updated with further info, try that please. :)

Comment: thanks but I get the same lack of anything on the page :(  my template simply has 'hello' in it

Comment: Hi James, got it working in a simplified jsFiddle. Please see my updated answer. :)

Comment: Hi @JamesRadford Did you get sorted for the list? Please accept the answer if it works for you? :)